# how to update react-native project to adapt iPhone x

Tags: react-native, iphone-x

I got an old react-native project some day before, then updated the react-native to 0.55.4, but my project still doesn't adapt the iPhone X.

Need some help please.

`"dependencies": {
 "react": "16.2.0",
  "react-native": "^0.55.4",
}`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use the new component provided in React Native 0.50.1 to deal with these case "SaveAreaView" : https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/safeareaview.html ?

There is an article in Medium which show some screen's rendering alone or coupled with React Navigation https://medium.com/react-native-training/react-native-iphonex-92ff511282af

If you use React Navigation, there was a similar issue reported on their github https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/2113 The problem was about a wrong sized splash screen.

Hope this helps !

Comment: I didn't use SaveAreaView nor Navigation. I just use a simple code replace my project.

Comment: Try with SafeAreaView then to see if it works ;-) About React Navigation in fact the issue wasn't related to it but just about a wrong sized splash screen : https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/2113#issuecomment-343165192. "[...] The black area on the top and bottom is gone after I added the right sized splash screen for iPhone X [...]" So if you use a splash screen make sure it has to correct size ;-)

Comment: Awesome!!!!  when I added the right sized splash screen for iPhone X,  it adapt the iPhone X. thank you very much.